# Sliding Drawer close on back button pressed

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a sliding drawer in my application.

It open when I click on `android:handle`, which I have given to an image view.

I want to close the drawer when back button is pressed.

Code:

```
SlidingDrawer slider;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
    slider.close ();
}           
super.onBackPressed();
```

Main. Xml file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<SlidingDrawer
android:id="@+id/slider"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:handle="@+id/handle"
android:content="@+id/content"

android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:background="@drawable/up"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity file

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    SlidingDrawer slide = (SlidingDrawer)this.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


@Override public void onBackPressed() { 
if(slide.isOpened()){ 
slide.close ();
}
else{
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You only need to close it if it's actually opened:

```
SlidingDrawer slider;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
    if (slider.isOpened()) {
        slider.close ();
    } else {           
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

EDIT

your `slider` field is out of [scope](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/4/lec/08). You need to declare it as a class field in order it can be accessed by all non-static methods. Also consult [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Comment: Still application crashes

Comment: Did you initialize your `SlidingDrawer` by using `findViewById`?

Comment: I have edited the question added the activity file code

Comment: do you init your `Drawer` outside of `onCreate()`? You do not have to use `this` btw

Comment: but your `Activity` code looks like that (paste mistake?). Please post your LogCat output (if you don't see the LogCat window at the bottom, use `Window - show View - LogCat`)

Comment: Have pasted the code as it is..I am using AIDE to code the application right now..

Comment: if you pasted the code "as is", this line `SlidingDrawer slide = (SlidingDrawer)this.findViewById(R.id.slider);` is outside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: you should also declare your `SlidingDrawer` as a class field and initialize it in `onCreate`

Comment: Okay I cut paste it inside.. it give me unknown entity error for the below code

Comment: Added the Edit in the question

Comment: init it AFTER calling `setContentView()`.

Comment: Done .. gives me unknows entity" slide" for the later code

Comment: did you import `android.widget.SlidingDrawer`?

Comment: I notice that you are missing some very basic Java knowledge. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the super method inside the in on back pressed method you just give this only...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
     slider.close ();
}
```

**Don't call Super method inside the back pressed**

Comment: will you able to post that logcat values it may give any solution for your problem